# How to configure Key configurations (namely: Token Endpoint and Revoke endpoint) in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have configured **WSO2 Identity Server (hereafter IS)** as Key Manager for **WSO2 API Manager (hereafter APIM)** following [this documentation](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/configuring-wso2-identity-server-as-a-key-manager/#step-5-configure-wso2-api-m-with-the-wso2-is). APIM and IS are installed on different servers.
Thereafter, I restarted both of them. But when I go to the devportal of APIM to generate access token, the addresses of token endpoint and revoke endpoint remain unchanged as depicted below:

[image: this pic.].

**The question** I would like to ask is how I can change these endpoint addresses to :

Token Endpoint:  https://iskm.dom.zu:9444/oauth2/token

Revoke Endpoint:  https://iskm.dom.zu:9444/oauth2/revoke

respectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change it to the host name of the Gateway by updating the `https_endpoint` value under `[[apim.gateway.environment]]` in the `deployment.toml`. In this case the host name of the token url will be updated to the host name of the Gateway you define. You also need to define `show_as_token_endpoint_url` as `true`. For more info, check [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/config-catalog/#api-m-gateway-environment-configurations).

Otherwise, if you have separate key-manager configurations, you can update the `service_url` value under `[apim.key_manager]` config in the `deployment.toml`. For more info, check [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/config-catalog/#api-m-key-manager-related-configurations). In this case, the host name of the token url will be the host name of the key-manager service

Answer (score 1):

You need to register a key manager by providing the relevant configurations (like token endpoint, revoke endpoint, authorize endpoint and client registration endpoint etc) in Admin Portal. Then you can select the relevant key manager from Dev Portal when generating token

Refer this [doc](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/key-managers/configure-wso2is-connector/) for the step by step guideline.

Comment: I followed the instruction given in aforementioned  [link](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/key-managers/configure-wso2is-connector/). 

But when I want to generate keys in devportal it gives me :
Error! You have partially-created keys. Please click 'Clean Up' button and try again.

Even though I cleaned up, It keeps giving same error

Comment: What is the error in the back-end (in wso2carbon.logs)?